# Catalog Search Index failed and products list doesn't work

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, reindex, elasticsearch

Last Friday, I installed a new module (ERP embedded). Since this installation, the products list is empty on frontend. I'm using Magento 2.4.2 on apache2/php 7.4.24.

I try to reindex but I have an error :
->bin/magento index:reindex
Catalog Search index process unknown error:
Item (Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\Stock\Status) with the same ID "1" already exists.

A single product is ok with a direct URL rewrite. I checked if URLs rewrite existing for the category, it's ok.

I used bin/magento setup:upgrade to update the database, no error, all it's ok.
I cleared and purged cache. I restarted elasticsearch.
I tried to use a backup before the installation of the ERP module (the products list was ok), but I have the same problem, the products list didn't work! I suppose it's a problem with elasticsearch.

I forced search engine within/magento config:set catalog/search/engine elasticsearch7 and I watched elasticsearch status.

curl http://localhost:9200 return :

```
{
  "name" : "XXXXXX",
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
  "cluster_uuid" : "DTqi_5JvSAKmdPpmjJgmgg",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "7.15.0",
    "build_flavor" : "default",
    "build_type" : "deb",
    "build_hash" : "79d65f6e357953a5b3cbcc5e2c7c21073d89aa29",
    "build_date" : "2021-09-16T03:05:29.143308416Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "8.9.0",
    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "6.8.0",
    "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "6.0.0-beta1"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

On Magento backend, connection with elasticsearch is ok.

What can I check? I don't have any more solution :(

I don't find something on StackExchange to help me.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Please try `bin/magento indexer:reset` before trying to reindex.